# Problema con el BufferedReader

Tags: java

Quiero leer una serie de números de un archivo de txt, entonces hice esto para probar si me daba el primer valor:

```
try {
        Path p = Paths.get("DatosEA.txt");
        File f = p.toFile();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String data;
        System.out.println("Revisión: " + br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Revisión (no de línea): " + br.read());

    br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Si en el DatosEA.txt está esto:

```
116
118
123
135
141
147
154
165
166
166
168
174
179
186
```

Pero me da de output esto:

```
Revisión: null
Revisión (no de línea): -1
```

¿Qué puede haber salido mal?
Cabe aclarar que todo esto está dentro de una clase que extiende JPanel llamada Grafico y lo llamo con un JPanel que es objeto de esa clase dentro de mi ventana. El código lo puse dentro de un método @Override paint de la clase Grafico.

Actualización: he puesto el código dentro del main de la clase principal de un proyecto nuevo y funciona perfectamente. Aún estoy buscando la fuente del error.

Comment: Hay alguna excepcion que estes capturando en un try catch?

Comment: Sip, ahí edito la pregunta y lo pongo. Listo.

Comment: Mira acabo de correr tu progrma y anduvo correctamente. Seguro que el archivo tiene datos? Por ahi los escribiste en un editor y no los guardaste con salvar.

Comment: Ahora he copiado y vuelto a pegar el código de otra forma y me anduvo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. No sé si eliminar esta pregunta.

Comment: tengo un buffered writer que se me causa el problema ahora veo.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné.